# Create a thread array with an instance of a class

Tags: java

I was wondering how I would be able to create a thread that has an instance of a class, however I would like to duplicate it, so it runs what ever is within the class the given amount of times. I tried doing 
    Thread[] t1 = new Thread[100];
Yet I could not find out how to put an instance of another class into that thread.

Class 1:

public class Main
{

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{   
   super.paintComponent(g);
   r.render(g);
   repaint();
}

public Main()
{
    setTitle("Graphics");
    setSize(1000,800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBackground(new Color(160, 160, 160));
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new Main(); 
}
```

}

Class 2:

public class Rain implements Runnable
{

Random rand = new Random();

```
int
x = rand.nextInt(1000),  
y = rand.nextInt(100) - 200,
length = rand.nextInt(40),
speed = rand.nextInt(11) + 1;

public void render(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + length);
}

public void move()
{
    if(y > 800)
        y = rand.nextInt(100) - 200;
    else
        y+= speed;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(6);
            move();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could `extend Thread` or `implement Runnable`.

Comment: I tried implementing runnable in the other class, i just want to run whatever is within that class 100 times.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you include some code to demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the main post. I just want to run whatever is within the Rain class 100 times.